# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main (when clicking a button app crashes)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, steganography

Hello everyone, My group for Thesis project is currently having problems on running our android app using Android Studio, The concept is Steganography and we are using an F5 Library from https://github.com/guardianproject/PixelKnot/tree/version_2/PixelKnot/src/main/java/info/guardianproject/pixelknot

[Here is our user interface and whenever clicking embed button, the app closes automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7T5C.jpg)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.angel.filepicker, PID: 2972
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void info.guardianproject.f5android.stego.StegoProcessor.addThread(info.guardianproject.f5android.stego.StegoProcessThread, boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.angel.filepicker.EmbedFragment$3.onClick(EmbedFragment.java:162)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

EmbedFragment.java code

```
package com.example.angel.filepicker;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import info.guardianproject.f5android.plugins.f5.Embed;
import info.guardianproject.f5android.stego.*;
import info.guardianproject.f5android.plugins.PluginNotificationListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
public class EmbedFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "EMbed";

    public EmbedFragment() {

    }

    private Activity a;

    public File finalFile;
    public File msgFile;

    public byte[] seed = new String("This is hopefully Temporary").getBytes();
    public String baseimage;
    public String secret_file;
    public Intent fileIntent;

    public static Activity act;
    public static Context cntx;

    public StegoProcessor stego_processor;
    //FOR FILE BUTTON

    public static final int FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    Intent intent;

    Button btn_choose_image;
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;

    //FOR IMAGE BUTTON
    File photoFile = null;
    static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;
    static final int SELECT_FILE = 3;

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.embed_fragment, container, false);

        cntx = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        act = getActivity();


        //initialize and set intent type

        fileIntent = new Intent();

        fileIntent.setType("*/*");

        fileIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


        text = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        //FOR FILE BUTTON
        Button pickButton = view.findViewById(R.id.pick_from_activity);
        pickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                checkPermissionsAndOpenFilePicker();
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Select File"), FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);


            }
        });

        //FOR IMAGE BUTTON
        btn_choose_image = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_image);
        image = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        btn_choose_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captureImage();
            }
        });


        final Button embedButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.embedButton);
        embedButton.setOnClickListener(embedButtonListener);

        return view;


    }

    View.OnClickListener embedButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

      if(baseimage !=null)

        {
            if ( secret_file != null) {

                //ImageSteganography Object instantiation
                Embed embed = new Embed(a,baseimage , secret_file, seed) {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        super.run();
                    }
                };
                stego_processor.addThread(embed, true);
            }
        }
    }

    };



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//        Log.e("onActivityResult", "requestCode " + requestCode + ", resultCode " + resultCode);


        if (requestCode == FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {


            Uri uri=data.getData();
            try{
                msgFile=new File(uri.getPath());//get the file
                secret_file = uri.getPath();
                //secretFile = getPathFromUri(getActivity(),uri);
                Toast.makeText(act.getBaseContext(), "Picked file: " + msgFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //text.setText(textx);
            }catch(Exception e){}
            if(msgFile.length()==0){
                try{
                    msgFile=new File(getPathFromUri(getActivity(),uri));//get the file
//                    secretFile = getPathFromUri(getActivity(),uri);
                    Toast.makeText(act.getBaseContext(), "Picked file: " + msgFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Main","Unable to get file!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//            baseImage = photoFile.getAbsoluteFile();

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());

            image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }

        //PROBLEMA NITO IS YUNG PAG DISPLAY NG PIC YUNG SIZE NG PIC .
        // MAY METHOD NA RESIZIND PERO TSAKA NA CGURO PAG NALAGAY NA UI
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
           // baseImage = getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), data.getData());
            Uri uri=data.getData();

            try {
                // mengambil gambar dari Gallery

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                baseimage = uri.getPath();
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                text.setText(baseimage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
//    private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
//        Cursor cursor = null;
//        try {
//            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
//            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
//            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
//            cursor.moveToFirst();
//            return cursor.getString(column_index);
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            Log.e(TAG, "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + e.toString());
//            return "";
//        } finally {
//            if (cursor != null) {
//                cursor.close();
//            }
//        }
//    }
    public static String getPathFromUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {//get path name from a uri object(source: web)

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

//...................................................................................................................................
    //FOR IMAGE BUTTON
    private void captureImage() {
        image.setImageResource(0);
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel"};
//ITO YUNG CHOICE KUNG TAKE PHOTO OR SELECT IMAGE . KAPAG TAKE PHOTO DAPAT
// NASASAVE SA GALLERY PERO WALA AKO NAKITA SA GALLERY KO HAHAH FEELING KO MAS OKAY PAG DI NLNG NASSASAVE

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {

                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        // Create the File where the photo should go
                        try {

                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                            displayMessage(getActivity().getBaseContext(), photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            Log.i("Stegrapp", photoFile.getAbsolutePath());

                            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                                        "com.example.angel.filepicker.fileprovider",
                                        photoFile);
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            // Error occurred while creating the File
                            displayMessage(getActivity().getBaseContext(), ex.getMessage().toString());
                        }


                    } else {
                        displayMessage(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Nullll");
                    }

                    //PROBLEMA NITO IS YUNG PAG DISPLAY NG PIC YUNG SIZE NG PIC .
                    // MAY METHOD NA RESIZIND PERO TSAKA NA CGURO PAG NALAGAY NA UI
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }


            }

        });
        builder.show();
    }

//........................................................................................................


    //ITO YUNG PAG CREATE NG FILE NUNG IMAGE GALING CAMERA
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void displayMessage(Context context, String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }






    public static void show(final String toast){
        act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(EmbedFragment.cntx,toast,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.angel.filepicker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

    ImageView imageView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    FloatingActionButton shareButton;
    Button btn_choose_image;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager_id);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_id);
        shareButton = findViewById(R.id.shareButton_id);




        //sharing
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                // this should be the file
                // must create folder the carrier image
                // this is a sample that takes string

                //intent takes string should be file
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                //should be the carrier image
                String shareBody = "Your body here";
                // can be removed / optional
                String shareSub = "Your subject here";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSub);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share using"));
            }
        });

        // SETTING UP ViewPagerAdapter
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.addElements(new EmbedFragment(), "Embed");
        viewPagerAdapter.addElements(new ExtractFragment(), "Extract");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);




    }

}
```

Comment: A `StegoProcessor` is declared but called after it is assigned. Show us what your code is.

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you. Basically post Embedfragment initialisation and full class usage

Comment: hello posted the EmbedFragment also the MainActivity @Sush

Comment: @GenoChen I added some of our code

Comment: Real. Can't find any code for assignment of `StegoProcessor stego_processor` in `EmbedFragment.java`.

Comment: @gel please check above comment from @Geno Chen. There is only declaration part not assignment part for `StegoProcessor stego_processor`